# How to implement touch when using quartz-2d

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, draw, quartz-2d

I'm using quartz-2d to do a school project. I have implement a user interface like the following.

[image]

**My question is how to implement touch function under quartz-2d ?** For example when I touch some area in the menu will draw another picture?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quartz or no, you're still drawing into a view, and you probably still have a view controller, right? Both the view and the view controller are subclasses of UIResponder, so implement the usual -touchesBegan:withEvent:, -touchesEnded:withEvent:, etc. Since it's probably your view that knows how the various parts of your UI are drawn, it would make sense for the view to handle the touches, figure out which part of the UI was touched, and send higher-level messages to the view controller.

Comment: Thanks Caleb. I add - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
 UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
 
 
} in my view. But still don't know how to get the touch event and how to control the response of the touch event.

Comment: `-touchesBegan:withEvent:` gives you both a set of touches and a touch event. There are several other related methods: `-touchesMoved...`, `-touchesEnded...`. Ways that you can use these to handle touches [are described in Apple's documentation](http://tinyurl.com/2bl5ab3). I'm not sure what more I can tell you in the small space.

Comment: Thanks for response. When I get event from -touchesBegan:withEvent, how to handle the UI dispaly? I need to redraw a menu pic as I shown in my original question. How to handle the redraw, still in the - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect ?

Comment: Your view should have some internal state that lets it keep track of how it should display itself. You might give it a `selectedSector` property that remembers which part of the view was touched. Your -touchesBegan... figures out which sector was touched, and sets the property correspondingly. If the touch slides over to another sector, -touchesMoved... sets the property again. When the touch ends, -touchesEnded... clears the property and sends a message to the view controller to let it know that something was tapped. -drawRect: looks at `selectedSector` to figure out how to draw the view.